# Iterator method?

Tags: java, iterator, linked-list, overflow

I'm implementing a list interface with links but since "ListADT" implements the Iterable interface. So, I have to have a method that produces an iterator which I'm not sure how to do. I tried using it as it is now and when I created an object for the linkedlist, and then call the iterator() method, I get an overflow. I know the method is supposed to produce an Iterator object but not sure how.

```
import java.util.Iterator;

public class LinkedList<T> implements ListADT<T> 
{ 
protected int count;
protected LinearNode <T> head, tail;
private  int modCount;

public LinkedList()
{
    count =0;
    head = tail= null;
}

 public T removeFirst()
 {
     T result = head.getElement();
     head = head.getNext();
     count--;
     return result;

 }

 public T removeLast()
 {
     // THROW EMPTY EXCEPTION

     T result;
     LinearNode <T> previous = null;
     LinearNode <T> current = head;
     while(!current.equals(tail))
     {
         previous = current;
         current = current.getNext();
     }
     result = tail.getElement();
     tail = previous;
     tail.setNext(null);
     count--;
     return result;

 }

 public T remove(T element)
 {
     // throw exception

     boolean found = false;
     LinearNode <T> previous = null;
     LinearNode <T> current = head;

     while (current != null && !found)
     {
         if(element.equals(current.getElement()))
             found = true;
         else
         {
             previous = current;
             current = current.getNext();
         }

         if (!found)
         {

         }
         else if (current.equals(head))
         {
             head = current.getNext();
         }
         else if(current.equals(tail))
         {
             tail = previous;
             tail.setNext(null);
         }
         else
             previous.setNext(current.getNext());
     }
     count --;
     return current.getElement();
 }

 public T first()
 {
    return head.getElement(); 
 }

 public T last()
 {
     return tail.getElement();
 }

 public boolean contains(T target)
 {
     boolean found = false;
     LinearNode <T> previous = null;
     LinearNode <T> current = head;

     while (current != null && !found)
     {
         if(target.equals(current.getElement()))
             found = true;
         else
         {
             previous = current;
             current = current.getNext();
         }
     }
     return found;
 }

 public boolean isEmpty()
 {
     boolean result = false;
     if( head == null && tail ==null)
     {
         result = true;
     }
     return result;
 }

 public int size()
 {
     return count;
 }

 public Iterator<T> iterator()
 {

    return this.iterator();
 }

 public String toString()
 {
     LinearNode <T> current = head;
     String result ="";
     String line = "";
     int loopCount=0;
     while(current != null)
     {
         loopCount++;
         line = loopCount + "> " + (String) current.getElement() + "\n";
         result = result + line;
         current = current.getNext();
     }
     return result;
 }
}
```

Comment: also, in java, open braces go at the end of lines http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-141270.html#381

Answer (score 1):

#### Your problem

You're getting an overflow because the line `this.iterator()` in your function `public Iterator<T> iterator()`, calls, you guessed it `public Iterator<T> iterator()`.

---

#### Approach 1: The lazy way

If you don't plan on using the iterator for this class, (this looks like a programming assignment) you can always do the super super lazy.

```
public Iterator<T> iterator() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Pffffft you don't need no iterator");
}
```

This approach is listed here just for completeness. Seeing as your linked list has no other way to access a random element in the middle without removing everything in front or behind it, I recommend you:

### DO NOT DO THIS

---

#### Approach 2: The Correct Way

The thing about iterators is that they do a specific subset of what a list does, namely `hasNext()`, `next()`, and `remove()`. If you're unsure what those three methods do, I suggest you take a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html

You should create a public inner class.

```
public class LinkedList<T> implements ListADT<T> {
    ... stuff

    private class MyIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {
        //It's best practice to explicitly store the head in the iterator
        private LinearNode<T> head;

        public MyIterator<T>(LinkedList<T>) {
            ...
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            ...
        }

        @Override
        public T next() {
            ...
        }

        @Override
        public void remove() {
            ...
        }
    }

    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
         return new MyIterator<T>(this);
    }
}
```

Now if you're really clever, you can rewrite the rest of your code based on the iterator. Note:

### DO THIS

Comment: Eclipse won't let me add that parameter to the constructor of the inner class: "- Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens
 - Syntax error on token ">", VariableDeclaratorId expected after 
  this token"